# How to increment a number with the form x.y.z with the use of indexing and all numbers to the right of it become 0

Tags: python

I'm having trouble with trying to increment a specific number that is in the form `x.y.z` using an index and making all numbers to the right of it become 0.

The final product should look like this:

```
4.2.11 => 4.3.0
```

I've tried putting `x.y.z` into a list so I can retrieve any value I want with an index but can't make them increment in any way.

Comment: Post the code you wrote

Comment: What number type is that?

Comment: This is just for incrementing a version number, right?  Yes, put them in a list.  If you bump item i, you set `range(i+1,len(list))` to 0.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only converting the one needed number to `int`, and by default incrementing the last number:

```
def increment(version, index=-1):
    nums = version.split('.')
    v = int(nums[index])
    nums[index:] = '0' * len(nums[index:])
    nums[index] = str(v + 1)
    return '.'.join(nums)

print(increment("4.2.11", 0))  # => 5.0.0
print(increment("4.2.11", 1))  # => 4.3.0
print(increment("4.2.11", 2))  # => 4.2.12
print(increment("4.2.11"))     # => 4.2.12
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fc7RCoIwFAbge5/iYBe6ssOmBiHYi4RXuWihc8wp9fRrapgFucv//37O1NPcGpkclba25FcQ8qJ5zaUJe65b0cjIRSV/5HtGMg/ck13dQg7vGltVCRMGGJCx7V0l3HpQ53FZkHk2BVnhTEAD2ELFZbgsfukgW6PDHnbAplJz02kJ7iDeGzHNiecpPVz9/N5PMUbG/AgoIQAbyE9wQIp0RbJZppisynghXRT/pYODL2rtCw)

Answer (score 1):

Convert the number to a list with `split`, and convert the list items to `int`s so you can increment one of them; then convert back to `str` and `join` to produce a string in the original format.

```
>>> def bump(version, index):
...     nums = [int(i) for i in version.split(".")]
...     nums[index] += 1
...     nums[index+1:] = [0] * (len(nums) - index - 1)
...     return ".".join(str(i) for i in nums)
...
>>> bump("4.2.11", 1)
'4.3.0'
>>> bump("4.2.11", 0)
'5.0.0'
>>> bump("4.2.11", 2)
'4.2.12'
```

Answer (score 1):

Keep the digits in a list and make a class to encapsulate the behaviour.

```
class X:
    def __init__(self,x):
        self.digits = [int(n) for n in x.split('.')]
    def __getitem__(self,item):
        return self.digits[item]
    def __setitem__(self,item,value):
        self.digits[item] = value
        for i in range(item+1,len(self.digits)):
            self.digits[i] = 0
    def __str__(self):
        temp = '.'.join('{}' for _ in self.digits)
        return temp.format(*self.digits)

>>> x = X('4.3.11')
>>> str(x)
'4.3.11'
>>> x[1] += 1
>>> str(x)
'4.4.0'
>>> x[0] += 1 
>>> str(x)    
'5.0.0'
>>>
```

Comment: That code looks like it can't decide whether it supports arbitrary lengths or just length 3.

Comment: You are right for the `__str__` function anyway.

Comment: That and `__setitem__`. One hardcodes the length, the other explicitly asks for the length.

Comment: Fixed `__str__`. Can you show an example where `__setitem__` fails?

Comment: I don't think it fails. Also not saying one way is better than the other. Just that there was an irritating *inconsistency*, as one was explicitly coded for a certain fixed length and the other was explicitly coded for arbitrary length. The `__init__` function also supports arbitrary length, but that's *implicit*, it works for both ways and is naturally written like it is. But `__setitem__`, if the solution assumes fixed length 3, would've naturally used `3` instead of `len(self.digits)`. That's what I mean with *explicitly* coded for arbitrary length.

Comment: I guess sometimes my answers are not finished products just examples to keep things brief and I don't see all pitfalls. Thnx.